# smart table no event is getting fired on setting the value through ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="filterPrivateDocCheckBox" ng-click="dl.filterPrivateDocument(filterPrivateDocCheckBox, $event)">
<input st-search="target" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" ng-model="dl.documentTarget"  />
```

**AngularJS**

```
 function filterPrivateDocument(val, event) {
    self.documentTarget = (val ? 'Private' : '');
 }
```

When I click on checkbox , I set some value in a textbox (which is hidden), but the problem is there is no event fire after setting the value in text box and hence smart table does not filter the data.

How can I solve this problem in smart table ??

Any help is appreciated !!

Thanks

Comment: In the function `filterPrivateDocument` where is scope ?

Comment: It is declared with this.filterPrivateDocument=filterPrivateDocument;

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
function filterPrivateDocument(val, event) {
    self.documentTarget = (val ? 'Private' : '');
}
```

should be

```
$scope.filterPrivateDocument(val, event) {
    self.documentTarget = (val ? 'Private' : '');
}
```

you should bind to `$scope` any property you want to expose to your HTML/template

because you are using controllerAs syntax, it should be

```
dl.filterPrivateDocument(val, event) {
    self.documentTarget = (val ? 'Private' : '');
}
```